# Schedule program to be updated weekly

Tags: python, csv, scheduled-tasks

I have some code that I am working on and I was needing some help on how to schedule my program to run weekly. I also was wanting to export my output to a CSV file and wasn't sure how to implement it into the code that I already have. I am getting stock information from https://www.eia.gov/petroleum/ here is my code is:

```
# Importing needed libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.eia.gov/petroleum/" # Specifiy which URL/web page we are going to be scrapping
res = requests.get(URL).text # Open the URl using requests
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')
for items in soup.find('table', class_='basic_table').find_all('tr')[1::1]: # Exception handling
    data = items.find_all(['td']) # Use 'find_all' function to bring back all instances
    try: # Looks up information in each specified data row
        stocks = data[0].text
        third_week = data[1].text
        second_week = data[2].text
        first_week = data[3].text
    except IndexError:pass
    print("{}| {}: {} | {}: {} | {}: {}".format(stocks, "Price in million barrels 3 weeks ago",third_week,"Price in million barrels 2 weeks ago",second_week,"Price in million barrels 1 week ago",first_week)) # Formatting my intended output
```

Comment: I recommend you to use Lambda and s3 services from Amazon Web Services. It's easy to learn and if the job is small probably will be totally free.

Comment: all Linux systems (server or desktop) have program `cron` (`cronjob`) to schedule tasks - and you don't have to change your code. Windows has also built-in scheduling system. Withouth scheduling system your code would have to run all time (24h/7days) and check current time in loop to recognize if it is time to run code again.

Comment: So I am able to import cronjob and then specify when I want my program to run? Sorry, I am very new to all of this!